# java 8 list of optionals collect to list compilation error

Tags: java, java-8

I am having trouble understanding difference between

```
Stream<Optional<Integer>> optionalStream = Stream.of(
                Optional.of(1),
                Optional.empty(),
                Optional.of(5));

List<Optional<Integer>> optionalList = optionalStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which works just fine and :

```
List<Optional<Integer>> optionalList1 = Stream.of(
                Optional.of(1),
                Optional.empty(),
                Optional.of(5)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where I receive error

```
Error:(138, 40) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer>
    lower bounds: java.util.Optional<? extends java.lang.Object>
```

Comment: Does the second work if you add a hint, e.g. `Stream.<Optional<Integer>>of(/*etc*/`?

Comment: yes! why exactly does that happen?

Comment: Well, you're just giving the type inference algorithm some more constraints. Actually, the easier one to add would be `Optional.<Integer>empty()`. It feels like you shouldn't have to do this, but <shrug> that's how it is in the current implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reduced the examples a bit, and tried to compile the with `-XDverboseResolution=all` to output information about the type inference:

```
final class One {
  void one() {
    Stream<Optional<Integer>> optionalStream = Stream.of(Optional.empty());
    List<Optional<Integer>> optionalList = optionalStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}

final class Two {
  void two() {
    List<Optional<Integer>> optionalList1 =
        Stream.of(Optional.empty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

In the case of `Two`, it looks like the deferred instantiation of `Stream.of` is done before even looking at the subsequent `collect`:

```
...
Two.java:9: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>of(T)
        Stream.of(Optional.empty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                 ^
  instantiated signature: (Optional<Object>)Stream<Optional<Object>>
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>of(T)
Two.java:9: Note: resolving method collect in type Stream to candidate 0
        Stream.of(Optional.empty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
...
```

(the "resolving method `collect` is the first mention of `collect`)

There is no `target-type` to constrain it; the instantiated signature shows that it's a `Stream<Optional<Object>>`.

If you look at the corresponding output for `One`:

```
...
One.java:8: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>of(T)
    Stream<Optional<Integer>> optionalStream = Stream.of(Optional.empty());
                                                        ^
  instantiated signature: (Optional<Integer>)Stream<Optional<Integer>>
  target-type: Stream<Optional<Integer>>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>of(T)
...
```

It gets this right because it knows a target type.

I can't say exactly why the deferred instantiation occurs at this point for `Two`, as I'm not familiar enough with the way the type inference is applied.

I *think* it's because the invocation of `Stream.of` isn't considered a poly expression, but I can't really convince myself why (see edit history for some incoherent ramblings).

---

The fix I'd suggest is to apply a type hint to the `Optional.empty()`, i.e. `Optional.<Integer>empty()`. This has the effect of getting the actual type of the `Optional` right earlier in the inference, so it is known at the time of the deferred instantiation, event though the target type is still unknown:

```
final class Three {
  void three() {
    List<Optional<Integer>> optionalList1 =
        Stream.of(Optional.<Integer>empty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}

...
Three.java:9: Note: resolving method of in type Stream to candidate 1
        Stream.of(Optional.<Integer>empty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
              ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: Optional<Integer>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 not applicable method found: <T#1>of(T#1...)
        (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
          (argument mismatch; Optional<Integer> cannot be converted to T#1[]))
      #1 applicable method found: <T#2>of(T#2)
        (partially instantiated to: (Optional<Integer>)Stream<Optional<Integer>>)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>of(T#1...)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>of(T#2)
Three.java:9: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>of(T)
        Stream.of(Optional.<Integer>empty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                 ^
  instantiated signature: (Optional<Integer>)Stream<Optional<Integer>>
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>of(T)
...
```

Answer (score 5):

`Stream.of(...)` or `Optional.empty()` are generic methods. If you don't provide the type parameter, it will be inferred. For `Optional.empty()` you'll get `Optional<Object>` so `Stream.of(Optional.of(1), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(5))` would result in `Stream<Optional<? extends Object>>`.

You can solve the issue by providing the type parameter in `Optional.<Integer>empty()` or `Stream.<Optional<Integer>>of(...)`. I'd prefer the first one.

Comment: "For `Optional.empty()` you'll get `Optional<Object>`" but you don't in the first case, otherwise it wouldn't work. This answer fixes the symptoms, but doesn't account for the difference.

Comment: Both the first and second cases in OP's code contain `Optional.empty()`. If, as you say, that is of type `Optional<Object>`, the first case wouldn't work either. (BTW, I'm not the downvoter).